# Can I use If Condition for this?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Assuming that my A1 is a column consist of countries and I want my A2 to show the list of cities on A1's choosen city. On my Sheet 2 I have the list of cities for a specific countries.

is it possible to use a column as a result?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dependency drop down lists using data validation option from column X to get relevant results in column Y.

More info and steps are in this [Link](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: I have an arranged columns already but I want to make a condition.

Ex.

IF A1 = America
then A2 = Sheet2!A1(which is a dropdown list contains Americas's Cities)

what conditional for mula could I possible to use?

Comment: Did you check the link ? it has a video which exactly specifies your use case under section **Dependent Drop Down Lists**